# Global error handling in for Express and GraphQL

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo

I have an Express server. I want it to expose a GraphQL interface and also a classic REST API.

It registers an apollo server as a middleware:

```js
async function startApolloServer(typeDefs, resolvers) {
    const app = express();
    const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
    const server = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
        formatError: (err) => {
            throw err;
        },
        plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })],
    });
    await server.start();
    app.use(server.getMiddleware());

    // Rest route
    app.get('/test', () => {
        throw new Error('Rest error')
    })
    
    // Error handling
    app.use((err, _req, res, _next) => {
        // Handle all errors
    });
    await new Promise(resolve => httpServer.listen({ port: 4000 }, resolve));
    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`);
}
```

I would like to handle both errors from the REST API and the GraphQL one in the Express middleware. I was expecting that throwing in the `formatError` would trigger the error handling express middleware but it does not.

Is there a way to do it?
Is that a good idea to create such a global handler?